# How set the monitor initially off using python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, monitor

Currently I have one project using Raspberry Pi Python language to turn on and off the monitor using a sensor.

How can I set the monitor to sleep mode in its initial state in python language?

```
    # Calculate pulse length
    elapsed = stop-start

    # Distance pulse travelled in that time is time
    # multiplied by the speed of sound (cm/s)
    distance = elapsed * 34000

    # That was the distance there and back so halve the value
    distance = distance / 2

    print "Distance : %.1f" % distance
    if(distance > 30):
        time.sleep(3)
        subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o",shell=True)


        os.system('clear')
    if(distance <= 30):
            subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p",shell=True)


   # Reset GPIO settings

   GPIO.cleanup()
```

This is part of my code, but I want to set the screen off in its initial state.

Comment: Do you have any code currently? Please edit your question to include it. It's quite hard to tell what you're actually trying to do at the moment.

Comment: Assuming `subprocess.call("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o",shell=True)` is the line that causes the monitor to switch off, can you not just run that command earlier in your script?